# After an unarmed creature disarms a foe, can the creature keep the weapon?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, weapons, combat-maneuver, unarmed-combat

I'm playing a brawler who uses unarmed strikes and who specializes in disarming foes. Can an unarmed brawler retain a weapon after he disarms an opponent since his hands are free when he makes the disarm attempt?

Comment: Welcome to the site! Take the [tour]! I've edited this to omit the extra questions—the site has a 1 question per post policy. If you'd like to pose the extra questions as new questions, that's fine, but bear in mind that site has pretty strict requirements for [optimization questions](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1639/8610), even if it's just optimizing gear. Anyway, thank you for participating and have fun.

Answer (score 3):

Yes. The disarm manuever says
"If you successfully disarm your opponent without using a
weapon, you may automatically pick up the item dropped."

So if you disarm someone while unarmed, you can take the weapon.

Comment: Thanks, but I wasn't sure whether or not it cost me and additional move action to pick it up or not since it says, "you may pick up the weapon" generally to pick up a weapon requires a move action that provides attacks of opportunity.

Comment: I can't think of what else "automatically" would mean. If it just meant they could pick it up with an action, that's no different than if they weren't unarmed or weren't the character that did the disarm.
3.5 was more explicit that you end up holding the weapon in this case, but of course that doesn't mean the same applies in Pathfinder.

Answer (score 1):

## The disarming creature can *pick up* the disarmed foe's stuff *automatically*—whatever *automatically* means

A creature that successfully performs the combat maneuver [disarm](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/gamemastering/combat#TOC-Disarm) against a foe yields the following results:

> [Y]our target drops one item it is carrying of your choice (even if the item is wielded with two hands). If your attack exceeds the CMD of the target by 10 or more, the target drops the items it is carrying in both hands (maximum two items if the target has more than two hands).

So, typically, a disarmed foe drops its stuff in a square (or in multiple adjacent squares if its really big stuff!) where the stuff can be retrieved *both* by the foe that had previously possessed the stuff *and* by the creature that disarmed the foe of that stuff.

However, an *unarmed* creature that succeeds on the combat maneuver disarm "may automatically pick up the [stuff that the foe] dropped" due to the disarm maneuver. Unfortunately, what exactly *automatically* means here isn't entirely clear.

At least two Paizo messageboard threads—one from [2011](https://paizo.com/threads/rzs2mxmk?Monk-Disarm-Question), another from [2014](https://paizo.com/threads/rzs2rnna?Unarmed-disarm-drops-item-even-on-success)—debate at length that *very* pregnant word *automatically*, insofar as they try to tackle *both* whether a disarmed foe's stuff actually lands on the surface below the foe and that surface is whence the creature must pick up the dropped stuff *and* whether the creature that automatically picks up the disarmed foe's stuff still provokes attacks of opportunity as is normal for picking up stuff.

In short it seems that a player relying on the combat maneuver disarm should ask the GM about the disarm maneuver's finer points. That is, can an unarmed creature that successfully disarms a foe pluck from the air the foe's now-falling stuff? Also, does an unarmed creature that *automatically* picks up the stuff that a foe dropped due to a successful disarm attempt provoke an attack of opportunity from opponents that threaten the unarmed creature? Only the GM can answer these questions.

#### Opinions are like elbows… typically, folks have two

Although this reader doesn't like it, this reader believes that *Pathfinder* would have a foe that fell victim to a successful disarm attempt drop its stuff on the surface beneath it *before* that stuff could be automatically picked up by the creature that disarmed the foe. Further—and this reader doesn't like this any more than the previous—, this reader believes that *Pathfinder* would have a creature provoke an attack of opportunity from trying to pick up automatically a foe's stuff that the foe dropped due to the creature's successful disarm, just as picking up stuff normally provokes attacks of opportunity.

Seriously, this GM and player thinks those outcomes are terrible and that if a creature is built to make unarmed disarm combat maneuvers, the payoff for specializing in that niche should be significant, especially since in the typical campaign many, many foes will be utterly immune to the disarm combat maneuver! With that in mind, in the typical campaign, this GM would likely rule that an unarmed combatant can, in fact, pluck out of the air—without provoking attacks of opportunity—a disarmed foe's falling stuff, and this player—were he playing such a specialist in a typical campaign—would encourage his GM to rule likewise.

---

***Note:*** Contrast the Pathfinder *combat maneuver [disarm](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/gamemastering/combat#TOC-Disarm) with its* D&D 3.5 *antecedent that in that earlier game's* Player's Handbook *on [Disarm](http://dndsrd.net/specialAttacks.html#disarm) says, "If you [succeeded on] the disarm while unarmed, you end up with the weapon in your hand" (155).*